# Take path "base" out of a path reliably

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have a program that takes `src` as source directory and `dst` as destination directory.

`src` could be `../ryver/test` or `../ryver/test/`. `dst` could be `/home/web/destination`.

I use `fs.readDir` to go through, so I end up with `../ryver/test/inside`, `../ryver/test/inside2`, `../ryver/test/inside2/again`, and so on.

In my program, I have to convert these files and place them in the same spot in dst. So, I have to find (or create), in `dst`, the right spot for them: they would be located in the same path but under `dst`, the way `cp -pr` would do it.

To get the correct destination path, the obvious answer is that I should take out `src` from the file path, so that for example `../ryver/test/inside2` becomes `inside2`, and then do `path.join( dst, result )` (where `result` is `inside2`).

However,  the fact that `src` could have the slash at the end means that it might need normalisation -- which is fine.

My question is, is there a simple, safe, accepted way to do this nicely, other than:

- adding a trailing `/` to src
- take `src` out of the beginning of the files' paths
- joining `dst` and the result

?

Comment: Is there anything complicated, dangerous, unacceptable about doing it this way? (Just make sure to "ONLY" add the trailing '/' if it's not already there)

Comment: I am not 100% sure, that's why I am asking. Normally when I come up with kludges like this, 1) They break at some point 2) I discover that there is a convenient command that does it. But maybe not this time!